# eslint error on deployment on local server of react web app

Tags: reactjs

There might be a problem with the project dependency tree.
It is likely not a bug in Create React App, but something you need to fix locally.

The react-scripts package provided by Create React App requires a dependency:

```
"eslint": "5.6.0"
```

Don't try to install it manually: your package manager does it automatically.
However, a different version of eslint was detected higher up in the tree:

```
D:\chintu\blog-exambunker-master\blog-exambunker-master\node_modules\eslint (version: 5.6.1)
```

how to install the version `5.6.0` I am installing the eslint it always gets installed with the latest version, can someone suggest me what to do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NPM start returns error, "There might be a problem with the project dependency tree"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56528222/npm-start-returns-error-there-might-be-a-problem-with-the-project-dependency-t)

Answer (score 11):

The error is an incompatibility between `eslint` and `babel-eslint` versions. To do solve this, firstly you need to remove your `eslint` package using `npm uninstall eslint`. This command will delete your `eslint` package. After this, you need to install the `5.6.0` version of `eslint`, so write this command `npm i eslint@5.6.0`. I hope that this will be helpful for you. Also, you can delete your `node_modules` folder and then install it.

Answer (score 3):

(Do not do what I did if you don't read everthing I posted) At least with me, I just downgraded my eslint 5.8.0 to 5.6.0 (manually). Why? Because when I use some eslint library like airbnb, it installs the latest version of eslint (5.8.0) automatically, the problem here is that this version has conflict with the previous eslint version used by react (5.6.0), so when you downgrade, you just return to the previous eslint installed, so it's working fine here, but you've to be careful when you update your react version.

Answer (score 2):

I have the exactly same problem. I have tried everithing from those Suggestions:

1. Delete `package-lock.json` (not `package.json`!) and/or `yarn.lock` in your project folder.
2. Delete `node_modules` in your project folder.
3. Remove `eslint` from `dependencies` and/or `devDependencies` in the `package.json` file in your project folder.
4. Run `npm install` or `yarn`, depending on the package manager you use.

In most cases, this should be enough to fix the problem.
If this has not helped, there are a few other things you can try:

5. If you used `npm`, install [`yarn`](http://yarnpkg.com/) and repeat the above steps with it instead.
   This may help because npm has known issues with package hoisting which may get resolved in future versions.
6. Check if `C:\Users\User\node_modules\eslint` is outside your project directory.
   For example, you might have accidentally installed something in your home folder.
7. Try running `npm ls eslint` in your project folder.
   This will tell you which other package (apart from the expected react-scripts) installed eslint.

nothing worked. every time I am doing `npm install/yarn` it keeps install the old version of eslint.

Comment: Me too couldn't find a solution for this

Answer (score 2):

I searched where the eslint was with:

```
npm ls eslint
```

then I deleted it with:

```
npm uninstall ls eslint
```

Finally I ran

```
npm start
```

and it worked.

Comment: this doesn't explain the root of the issue that OP is struggling with, reinstalling every time doesn't look like a solution but a workaround

Answer (score 2):

Create a file `.env` in your root directory.

And you can ignore the check by putting

```
SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true
```

in `.env` file.

Ref: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/5247#issuecomment-427221678

Edit: This is not the solution to this problem. It is just to ignore the error as it is discussed in the issue.

Answer (score 0):

ok I find my issue: I had npm packeges and some more crap outside the projects folders (on c:/users/user) they may had the old version of eslint. cheack it out and tell me if you still have the problem or not.

Answer (score 0):

I deleted a node modules folder that contained an older version of eslint. I found this to be the easiest solution rather than changing dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

What solved this for me, was that in the error message, it told me that there was eslint installed in project with `5.6.0` and another installed in `users/andrew/nodemodules/eslint` with a version of `4.1.6` I tried doing a `npm uninstall -g eslint` but that didnt work so then I just searched for all the files and folders within `users/andrew/nodemodules/eslint`
and deleted them, and it worked for then.
I'm not sure if this is a good way to do it, but its worked.

Answer (score 0):

Simple delete package-lock.json and node_modules then                                          run **npm install** then
**npm start**

else you could install 
**npm i eslint@5.6.0** then
**npm start**

enjoy your work :)

- List item

Answer (score 0):

Open a **NEW** terminal window within root.

Run the command

```
npm ls eslint
```

this should show you the installations that are 'higher' up the dependency tree.

Navigate into the folder(s) that contain gulp-eslint/eslint/babel-eslint or even a sneaky node_modules/ that shouldn't have been installed globally.

Next, run either or all of these commands depending on where the files are situated.

```
rm -rf node_modules/
rm -rf (name of other folders like eslint/gulp-eslint)
```

**RETURN TO YOUR PROJECT**

Better to be safe than sorry, run the following commands to make sure it will work properly again.

Within the root directory of your project

```
rm -rf node_modules/
rm -rf package-lock.json
```

(If it didn't remove the node_modules just delete it from your folder)

Finally, Run the following.

```
npm install
```

then

```
npm start
```

Answer (score 0):

go to node_modules folder and open react-scripts/package.json , find the eslint dependencies and change it. its fixed this way.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/wesbos/eslint-config-wesbos/issues/17

In the above mentioned link they suggested to install @abhijithvijayan/eslint-config as peer dependency. See if this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

you might install a global eslint like this

```
{22:14}~/go/src/github.com ➭ npm ls eslint      
/Users/demon
└── eslint@6.1.0
```

then run

```
{22:14}~/go/src/github.com ➭ npm uninstall eslint
```

in the global terminal instead of vscode's terminal. then run

```
npm start
```

Answer (score 0):

I just used this command: "npm uninstall eslint". Later I just ran mu=y code using npm run start and it worked. I did not have to delete or edit any file

Answer (score -3):

Add SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true to an .env file in your project.

Comment: That does not solve the problem, it just hides the error message

Answer (score -4):

There might be a problem with the project dependency tree.
It is likely not a bug in Create React App, but something you need to fix locally.

The react-scripts package provided by Create React App requires a dependency:

"eslint": "5.6.0"

Don't try to install it manually: your package manager does it automatically.
However, a different version of eslint was detected higher up in the tree:

/Users/macbook/node_modules/eslint (version: 3.19.0)

Manually installing incompatible versions is known to cause hard-to-debug issues.

If prefer to ignore this check, add SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true to an .env file in your project.
That will permanently disable this message but you might encounter other issues.

To fix the dependency tree, try following the steps below in the exact order:

1. Delete package-lock.json (not package.json!) and/or yarn.lock in your project folder.
2. Delete node_modules in your project folder.
3. Remove "eslint" from dependencies and/or devDependencies in the package.json file in your project folder.
4. Run npm install or yarn, depending on the package manager you use.

In most cases, this should be enough to fix the problem.
If this has not helped, there are a few other things you can try:

5. If you used npm, install yarn (http://yarnpkg.com/) and repeat the above steps with it instead.
    This may help because npm has known issues with package hoisting which may get resolved in future versions.
6. Check if /Users/macbook/node_modules/eslint is outside your project directory.
    For example, you might have accidentally installed something in your home folder.
7. Try running npm ls eslint in your project folder.
    This will tell you which other package (apart from the expected react-scripts) installed eslint.

If nothing else helps, add SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true to an .env file in your project.
That would permanently disable this preflight check in case you want to proceed anyway.

P.S. We know this message is long but please read the steps above :-) We hope you find them helpful!

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! my-app@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the my-app@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/macbook/.npm/_logs/2018-11-01T15_26_42_405Z-debug.log

Comment: Congratulation, you copy-pasted the full error message, but this is not an answer