# 'npm start' returns error: "There might be a problem with the project dependency tree"

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, create-react-app

I'm new to coding and having issues with why I can no longer get React set up correctly. I struggled with this last week and then finally managed it. But now I have had the same issue again and nothing is working.

I have a project which I started with `npx create-react-app` and then when I `cd` into the project I get this issue:

> There might be a problem with the project dependency tree. It is
> likely not a bug in Create React App, but something you need to fix
> locally.
>
> The react-scripts package provided by Create React App requires a
> dependency:
>
> "webpack": "4.29.6"
>
> Don't try to install it manually: your package manager does it
> automatically. However, a different version of webpack was detected
> higher up in the tree:
>
> /Users/aliceparker/node_modules/webpack (version: 4.33.0)
>
> Manually installing incompatible versions is known to cause
> hard-to-debug issues.
>
> If you would prefer to ignore this check, add
> SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true to an .env file in your project. That will
> permanently disable this message but you might encounter other issues.
>
> To fix the dependency tree, try following the steps below in the exact
> order:
>
> 1. Delete package-lock.json (not package.json!) and/or yarn.lock in your project folder.
> 2. Delete node_modules in your project folder.
> 3. Remove "webpack" from dependencies and/or devDependencies in the package.json file in your project folder.
> 4. Run npm install or yarn, depending on the package manager you use.
>
> In most cases, this should be enough to fix the problem. If this has
> not helped, there are a few other things you can try:
>
> 5. If you used npm, install yarn (http://yarnpkg.com/) and repeat the above steps with it instead.
>    This may help because npm has known issues with package hoisting which may get resolved in future versions.
> 6. Check if /Users/aliceparker/node_modules/webpack is outside your project directory.
>    For example, you might have accidentally installed something in your home folder.
> 7. Try running npm ls webpack in your project folder.
>    This will tell you which other package (apart from the expected react-scripts) installed webpack.
>
> If nothing else helps, add SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true to an .env file
> in your project. That would permanently disable this preflight check
> in case you want to proceed anyway.
>
> P.S. We know this message is long but please read the steps above :-)
> We hope you find them helpful!

I've followed the steps above. Still get the issue.
I've also uninstalled webpack globally and re-installed it.

Here is what my package.json file looks like:

```
`{
  "name": "ravenous-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-scripts": "3.0.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}`
```

Can anyone kindly guide me through ways to solve this?
(PS. I tried just creating a new project, but get the same issue...)

Comment: Just note, since neither deletion of node_modules or silencing of the error is a great solution for production, this warning likely comes from a conflict between two different packages at different stages, requiring different webpacks. Eg react scripts wants one webpack and storybook wants another.

Comment: Go and check this post... It help me https://stackoverflow.com/a/60947470/11510800

Answer (score 35, accepted):

In the terminal, run:

`cd ~`

Then:

`ls`

You should see a list of files. If `node_modules` is included in that list (as it appears it should be), you want to delete that folder. You can do so in the terminal like so:

`rm -rf node_modules`

But keep in mind: this will not send the folder to the trash. It will irrevocably delete it. `rm -rf` is a powerful command. If that makes you nervous, type `open .` instead. That will open your "home" (`~`) directory in Finder, and you can delete `node_modules` in the familiar, right-click, send-to-trash way there.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Are you getting the same error messages as in the original post? Or something different? Edit: Did you `cd` back into the project directory before running `npm start`?

Comment: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! react-app@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the react-app@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/alice/.npm/_logs/2019-06-10T14_56_11_380Z-debug.log
Alices-MBP-7:react-app alice$

Comment: Hm, maybe this thread will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42308879/npm-err-code-elifecycle

Comment: Unfortunately not :( I'm just back at the same issue when I complete the steps, re-install npm and then npm start.

Comment: Are you still seeing this message? "However, a different version of webpack was detected higher up in the tree: /Users/aliceparker/node_modules/webpack"

Comment: Yes, it is still there. Shall I delete webpack from the global user folder?

Comment: Yes you should delete `node_modules` and `package-lock.json` from `/Users/aliceparker`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53497035/why-there-is-a-node-modules-folder-under-my-home-folder

Comment: Yes!! Thank you! Wow I have been going round in circles all weekend on this! 

What I did: deleted the node modules and package-lock from global (perhaps i hadn't deleted both previously) and then npm cache verify.

Comment: Just to specify, I had done all the steps to solve the problem and no matter what it didn't work. I discovered that I had a node_modules folder in my user's folder. I deleted this one, but not the one in my project and then could use "npm start" whitout any issue.

Comment: I have ran into the same issue and after some research here are some thoughts: react js, does not require webpack and this is the dependency which is causing the errors, as it is not meeting the peer dependencies. So the simplest thing I have done is: removed webpack and babel dependencies and my app ran smoothly. By the way I am using react version 17.0.2. For further reading you may check the link https://javascript.plainenglish.io/why-you-should-not-use-webpack-f07f4fd7c116

Comment: @Seb - Thank you!!! Was having the same issue and couldn't figure out the solution until I found your comment.

Comment: why there are node_modules installed in my home dir?

Answer (score 62):

In my case, I solved my problem in this way

1. create a `.env` at the root of the folder `react folder`
2. type `SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true` inside of `.env` file
3. now run in cmd `npm start` .

Comment: What does this .env file actually do? Curious

Comment: @NehaChaudhary  that will permanently disable this preflight check

Comment: The hero we need, but don't deserve.

Comment: You are simply bypassing the error message. Not fixing the issue

Answer (score 15):

Delete `package-lock.json` (not `package.json`!) and/or `yarn.lock` in your project folder.

Delete `node_modules` in your project folder.

Remove `webpack` from dependencies and/or devDependencies in the `package.json` file in your project folder.

Run `npm install` or `yarn`, depending on the package manager you use.

I tried all of the above and it was not working but once i added a .env file to my project structure and added `SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true`  into the file. i could bypass the problem:

[image: problem solved]

This what you put inside the `.env` file:

[image: This what you put inside the .env file]

Answer (score 7):

you need to try
first, make a file with the name `.env` and store the `SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true`

> `root/.env`  and `.env` should contain `SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true`

Answer (score 4):

1. create a `.env` file or edit exiting one.
2. `SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK = true` write this to `.env` file.
3. restart dev server.

I solved the problem this way.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is the webpack installed in your user directory.
Remove it with npm or by hand and all should run fine:
ref: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/6120

Comment: Thanks, how would I remove it from my user directory? This is all a little over my head!

Comment: Yes, that was installed with _npm install ... -g_ flag, this is conflicting with your local installation

Answer (score 2):

You can follow the instructions given in the error log.

1. Delete `package-lock.json` (not `package.json`!) and/or `yarn.lock` in
   your project folder.
2. Delete `node_modules` in your project folder.
3. Remove "webpack" from dependencies and/or devDependencies in the
   `package.json` file in your project folder.
4. Run `npm install` or `yarn`, depending on the package manager you use.

Comment: Thanks. I have tried these steps already but just be clear, I wasn't sure on if I did step 3 correctly. How exactly do I do that?

Comment: open package.json, under dependencies or devDependencies remove reference to webpack.

Comment: There is no reference to the webpack there.. "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-scripts": "3.0.1"
  },

Answer (score 2):

- add "webpack": "4.44.2" to dependencies of `package.json`.
- create `.env` and type `SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true`
  That will be solved your problem.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I removed node_modules from my user's directory. It worked.

Answer (score 1):

The solution that worked for me

Add `SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true` to a .env file in your project. I don't know if this may result in errors in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the node_modules from your user directory i.e C:\Users\User

Comment: I've tried all the above methods but I completely forgot about removing my node modules from C:\Users\user folder. Thanks a lot @Emmanuel

Answer (score 1):

Add the line`"webpack": "4.44.2"` to the dependencies of your `package.json` file.
Create the `.env` file, and type `SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true` inside, which will solve your problem.

Comment: This does not solve the problem, it is a workaround disabling the preflight check and might have other consequences.

Answer (score 1):

I've been stuck on this for over an hour. I followed every step listed.
I deleted node_modules from my project and ALL node modules folders found on my mac.
Then I deleted packagelock and then ran `npm install` which gave me a fresh nm and packagelock.

Running `npm start` keeps giving me the same error. I know it's not my code because I can checkout another branch and I get the same error.

This all started when I installed react testing library and upgraded react-scripts from 2.1.1 to 4.*.*
I upgraded due to an error after running a test that said something about react-scripts (I can't remember what it said exactly.)

I have since reset my package.json to the old working version with the old react-scripts version and without the testing libraries, followed all the above steps again, and still have the error.

I don't have webpack in dependencies or dev dependencies.

Here is my previously working package.json

```
{
    "name": "bidrlfront",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "private": true,
    "homepage": "./",
    "dependencies": {
      "@date-io/moment": "^1.3.13",
      "@material-ui/core": "^4.12.3",
      "@material-ui/icons": "^4.11.2",
      "@material-ui/pickers": "^3.3.10",
      "camelize": "^1.0.0",
      "chart.js": "^2.7.3",
      "classnames": "^2.2.6",
      "cross-env": "^5.2.0",
      "css-loader": "^1.0.0",
      "dateformat": "^3.0.3",
      "flux": "^3.1.3",
      "lodash.find": "^4.6.0",
      "moment": "^2.29.1",
      "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
      "react": "^16.14.0",
      "react-bootstrap": "^1.6.1",
      "react-dom": "^16.6.3",
      "react-ga": "^2.5.6",
      "react-loading": "^2.0.3",
      "react-quill": "^1.3.3",
      "react-router": "^4.3.1",
      "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
      "react-scripts": "2.1.1",
      "shards-react": "^1.0.0",
      "shortid": "^2.2.14"
    },
    "scripts": {
      "start": "react-scripts start",
      "build:prod": "cross-env REACT_APP_BASENAME=/demo/shards-dashboard-lite-react REACT_APP_GAID=UA-115105611-1 npm run build",
      "build": "cross-env REACT_APP_BASENAME=/demo/shards-dashboard-lite-react react-scripts build",
      "test": "react-scripts test",
      "scss": "node-sass --watch -include-path src/css -o css",
      "eject": "react-scripts eject",
      "gitty": "node g.js"
    },
    "eslintConfig": {
      "extends": "react-app"
    },
    "browserslist": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not ie <= 11",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "devDependencies": {
      "sass-loader": "^7.1.0"
    },
    "repository": {
      "type": "git",
      "url": "git+ssh://git@bitbucket.org/rldev2/bidrl-app.git"
    },
    "keywords": [],
    "author": "Stephanie Raymos <sraymos@rlliquidators.com>",
    "license": "ISC"
  }
```

And here is my package.json when the errors started occuring

```
{
    "name": "bidrlfront",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "private": true,
    "homepage": "./",
    "dependencies": {
        "@date-io/moment": "^1.3.13",
        "@material-ui/core": "^4.12.3",
        "@material-ui/icons": "^4.11.2",
        "@material-ui/pickers": "^3.3.10",
        "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.14.1",
        "@testing-library/react": "^12.0.0",
        "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.2.1",
        "camelize": "^1.0.0",
        "chart.js": "^2.7.3",
        "classnames": "^2.2.6",
        "cross-env": "^5.2.0",
        "css-loader": "^1.0.0",
        "dateformat": "^3.0.3",
        "flux": "^3.1.3",
        "lodash.find": "^4.6.0",
        "moment": "^2.29.1",
        "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
        "react": "^16.14.0",
        "react-bootstrap": "^1.6.1",
        "react-dom": "^16.6.3",
        "react-ga": "^2.5.6",
        "react-loading": "^2.0.3",
        "react-quill": "^1.3.3",
        "react-router": "^4.3.1",
        "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
        "react-scripts": "^2.1.1",
        "shards-react": "^1.0.0",
        "shortid": "^2.2.14"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "start": "react-scripts start",
        "build:prod": "cross-env REACT_APP_BASENAME=/demo/shards-dashboard-lite-react REACT_APP_GAID=UA-115105611-1 npm run build",
        "build": "cross-env REACT_APP_BASENAME=/demo/shards-dashboard-lite-react react-scripts build",
        "test": "react-scripts test",
        "scss": "node-sass --watch -include-path src/css -o css",
        "eject": "react-scripts eject",
        "gitty": "node g.js"
    },
    "eslintConfig": {
        "extends": "react-app"
    },
    "browserslist": [
        ">0.2%",
        "not dead",
        "not ie <= 11",
        "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "devDependencies": {
        "sass-loader": "^7.1.0"
    },
    "repository": {
        "type": "git",
        "url": "git+ssh://git@bitbucket.org/rldev2/bidrl-app.git"
    },
    "keywords": [],
    "author": "Stephanie Raymos <sraymos@rlliquidators.com>",
    "license": "ISC"
}
```

I had also globally installed testing library and fsevents prior to the error occuring but uninstalled those and trashed the folders on my mac.

I installed fsevents after receiving this error when I attempted to run my app after installing the testing libraries:
Error: `fsevents` unavailable (this watcher can only be used on Darwin)

I was getting a blank screen. This solved that issue.
I then got an error logging with my auth system.
I was using rxjs. I had to install that.
Got a react-scripts error and updated that to the latest version.
That's when everything broke.
When I run `npm ls webpack` I get this:

```
├─┬ css-loader@1.0.1
│ └─┬ webpack@4.46.0
│   └─┬ terser-webpack-plugin@1.4.5
│     └── webpack@4.46.0 deduped
├─┬ react-scripts@2.1.1
│ ├─┬ babel-loader@8.0.4
│ │ └── webpack@4.46.0 deduped
│ ├─┬ css-loader@1.0.0
│ │ └── webpack@4.19.1 deduped
│ ├─┬ eslint-loader@2.1.1
│ │ └── webpack@4.46.0 deduped
│ ├─┬ file-loader@2.0.0
│ │ └── webpack@4.46.0 deduped
│ ├─┬ fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin-alt@0.4.14
│ │ └── webpack@4.46.0 deduped
│ ├─┬ html-webpack-plugin@4.0.0-alpha.2
│ │ └── webpack@4.46.0 deduped
│ ├─┬ mini-css-extract-plugin@0.4.3
│ │ └── webpack@4.46.0 deduped
│ ├─┬ optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin@5.0.1
│ │ └── webpack@4.46.0 deduped
│ ├─┬ sass-loader@7.1.0
│ │ └── webpack@4.19.1 deduped
│ ├─┬ terser-webpack-plugin@1.1.0
│ │ └── webpack@4.46.0 deduped
│ ├─┬ url-loader@1.1.1
│ │ └── webpack@4.46.0 deduped
│ ├─┬ webpack-dev-server@3.1.9
│ │ ├─┬ webpack-dev-middleware@3.4.0
│ │ │ └── webpack@4.46.0 deduped
│ │ └── webpack@4.46.0 deduped
│ ├─┬ webpack-manifest-plugin@2.0.4
│ │ └── webpack@4.46.0 deduped
│ ├─┬ webpack@4.19.1
│ │ └─┬ uglifyjs-webpack-plugin@1.3.0
│ │   └── webpack@4.46.0 deduped
│ └─┬ workbox-webpack-plugin@3.6.3
│   └── webpack@4.46.0 deduped
└─┬ sass-loader@7.3.1
  └── webpack@4.46.0 deduped
```

Answer (score 1):

The simple solution is just to install the webpack version shown in error.

**npm install webpack@version show in error.**

I hope this will help you.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your tree folder on your computer when you make all projects,try the app in folder not on exist one and  i hope it will work

Answer (score 0):

Do as it's saying on the error to make it work.
Create a `.env` file in your project directory and add `SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true`, it will work.

Comment: This is not a solution, in most cases it will just hide the error but other problems arise later.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same problem before and I solved it.
The `create-react-app` already provided `webpack(v4.29.6)`, which conflicts with `webpack(v4.33.0)` in `/Users/aliceparker/node_modules`.

So if you remove the second `webpack(v4.33.0)`, it would run.

Answer (score 0):

I created project using npx and I was getting same error with babel-eslint initially. I followed @davidflyod91 approach, it worked for me. Im not happy with deleting the whole node_module folder from ~ directory (in my MAC)(i mean to say the place where -g modules are installed). So, I put back the node_modules and deleted folders associate with below ones from node_modules in ~/node_modules directory and tried running the application (npm run start).

- Webpack
- babel
- eslint
- create-react-app

And then application started working.

Answer (score 0):

create an .env file and put this line "SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true"

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ITOnS.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can simply delete the `node_module` folder. it will work. Go to the root and then run the following command

```
sudo rm -rf /Users/yourname/node_modules
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error and none of the solutions helped me fully. Then I actually followed the instructions on the error and the issue was resolved

1. Deleted package-lock.json
2. Delete node_modules in the project folder.
3. Make sure to run npm install. If you dont and go straight to npm start you will have a "react-scripts: command not found error"

Edit:Issue reoccured and was resolved by adding the .env file to the  root of my project and added SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true into the file.

Issue was fully resolved now.

Comment: Using SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK is probably not a great idea because you're suppressing the issue and not resolving the problem. If the error persists, it's better to find the conflicting dependencies and resolving those.

Comment: Using SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK is probably not a great idea because you're suppressing the issue and not resolving the problem. If the error persists, it's better to find the conflicting dependencies and resolving those

Answer (score 0):

- First try `npm install`, then `npm start`
- If it doesn't work then run `npm audit`
- Then try `npm audit fix` or `npm audit fix --force`, then `npm install`, then `npm start`
- If it still doesn't work, **delete** *node modules*, *package-lock.json* and again try `npm install`, then `npm start`

> Still getting error? Set `SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true` inside of `.env` file

**And try again**.

Answer (score 0):

I had .env with SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true in it.

Deleted node_modules, reinstalled and got same error, including suggestion to add .env I already had.

So, I deleted .env and added it again with the same SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true in it.

The problem was solved.

Answer (score -1):

To fix the dependency tree, try following the steps below in the exact order:

1. Delete package-lock.json (not package.json!) and/or yarn.lock in your project folder.
2. Delete node_modules in your project folder.
3. Remove "webpack" from dependencies and/or devDependencies in the package.json file in your project folder.
4. Run npm install or yarn, depending on the package manager you use.

In most cases, this should be enough to fix the problem.
If this has not helped, there are a few other things you can try:

5. If you used npm, install yarn (http://yarnpkg.com/) and repeat the above steps with it instead.
   This may help because npm has known issues with package hoisting which may get resolved in future versions.
6. Check if /home/omage/node_modules/webpack is outside your project directory.
   For example, you might have accidentally installed something in your home folder.
7. Try running npm ls webpack in your project folder.
   This will tell you which other package (apart from the expected react-scripts) installed webpack.

If nothing else helps, add SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true to an .env file in your project.
That would permanently disable this preflight check in case you want to proceed anyway.

Answer To fix the dependency tree

to solve a dependency tree problem, you have to delete the node-modules file from your local computer and run npm start , to start the localhost

Answer (score -1):

I created .env file and i added SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true in it.

Note: don't give any name to .env file, created filname must be .env

[picture for more understanding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rEde0.png)