# "babel-eslint" can't let me install react

Tags: reactjs, npm, babel-eslint

I am setting up a new react App, having installed it, i then added a name to the react app i begin to have a `babel-eslint` issue

> portfolio@0.1.0 start C:\Users\Samson Adedayo\Desktop\portfolio
>   react-scripts start

There might be a problem with the project dependency tree.
It is likely not a bug in Create React App, but something you need to fix locally.

The react-scripts package provided by Create React App requires a dependency:

"babel-eslint": "10.0.2"

Don't try to install it manually: your package manager does it automatically.
However, a different version of babel-eslint was detected higher up in the tree:

C:\Users\Samson Adedayo\Desktop\node_modules\babel-eslint (version: 10.0.1)

Manually installing incompatible versions is known to cause hard-to-debug issues.

If you would prefer to ignore this check, add SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true to an .env file in your project.
That will permanently disable this message but you might encounter other issues.

To fix the dependency tree, try following the steps below in the exact order:

1. Delete package-lock.json (not package.json!) and/or yarn.lock in your project folder.
2. Delete node_modules in your project folder.
3. Remove "babel-eslint" from dependencies and/or devDependencies in the package.json file in your project folder.
4. Run npm install or yarn, depending on the package manager you use.

In most cases, this should be enough to fix the problem.
If this has not helped, there are a few other things you can try:

5. If you used npm, install yarn (http://yarnpkg.com/) and repeat the above steps with it instead.
    This may help because npm has known issues with package hoisting which may get resolved in future versions.
6. Check if C:\Users\Samson Adedayo\Desktop\node_modules\babel-eslint is outside your project directory.
    For example, you might have accidentally installed something in your home folder.
7. Try running npm ls babel-eslint in your project folder.
    This will tell you which other package (apart from the expected react-scripts) installed babel-eslint.

If nothing else helps, add SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true to an .env file in your project.
That would permanently disable this preflight check in case you want to proceed anyway.

P.S. We know this message is long but please read the steps above :-) We hope you find them helpful!

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! portfolio@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the portfolio@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Samson Adedayo\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2019-09-11T18_30_41_153Z-debug.log

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NPM start returns error, "There might be a problem with the project dependency tree"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56528222/npm-start-returns-error-there-might-be-a-problem-with-the-project-dependency-t)

Answer (score 4):

Create `.env` file in your react-app folder and paste below line in it

```
SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true
```

your problem will get solve

Answer (score 2):

I was having this same issue. Occasionally the create-react-app does not install its dependencies correctly. To solve this I did the following:

- delete the node modules folder
- delete package-lock.json (NOT PACKAGE.JSON)
- manually add the babel-eslint to your package.json
- To do this add `"babel-eslint": "10.0.2"` to the end of your
  dependencies list

  - finally, run `npm i` and you should be good to go