# Getting an error trying to start React right after (There might be a problem with the project dependency tree....)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

I have created React App from npx create-react-app. And, I tried to cd and start the app and it shows this error. I tried with yarn and reinstalling node as well. I am super lost since it was wooooorking like 30 minutes ago as well. The only thing I did was npm i -g npm to update npm and since then it is not working.

```
We suggest that you begin by typing:

  cd giact
  yarn start

Happy hacking!
gi@Gis-Macbook-Pro study % cd giact
gi@Gis-Macbook-Pro giact % npm start

> giact@0.1.0 start /Users/gi/Desktop/Study/giact
> react-scripts start


There might be a problem with the project dependency tree.
It is likely not a bug in Create React App, but something you need to fix locally.

The react-scripts package provided by Create React App requires a dependency:

  "babel-eslint": "10.1.0"

Don't try to install it manually: your package manager does it automatically.
However, a different version of babel-eslint was detected higher up in the tree:

  /Users/gi/node_modules/babel-eslint (version: 9.0.0) 

Manually installing incompatible versions is known to cause hard-to-debug issues.

If you would prefer to ignore this check, add SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true to an .env file in your project.
That will permanently disable this message but you might encounter other issues.

To fix the dependency tree, try following the steps below in the exact order:

  1. Delete package-lock.json (not package.json!) and/or yarn.lock in your project folder.
  2. Delete node_modules in your project folder.
  3. Remove "babel-eslint" from dependencies and/or devDependencies in the package.json file in your project folder.
  4. Run npm install or yarn, depending on the package manager you use.

In most cases, this should be enough to fix the problem.
If this has not helped, there are a few other things you can try:

  5. If you used npm, install yarn (http://yarnpkg.com/) and repeat the above steps with it instead.
     This may help because npm has known issues with package hoisting which may get resolved in future versions.

  6. Check if /Users/gi/node_modules/babel-eslint is outside your project directory.
     For example, you might have accidentally installed something in your home folder.

  7. Try running npm ls babel-eslint in your project folder.
     This will tell you which other package (apart from the expected react-scripts) installed babel-eslint.

If nothing else helps, add SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true to an .env file in your project.
That would permanently disable this preflight check in case you want to proceed anyway.

P.S. We know this message is long but please read the steps above :-) We hope you find them helpful!

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! giact@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the giact@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/gi/.npm/_logs/2020-04-19T18_13_36_022Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NPM start returns error, "There might be a problem with the project dependency tree"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56528222/npm-start-returns-error-there-might-be-a-problem-with-the-project-dependency-t)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) The react-scripts package provided by Create React App requires a dependency:

"babel-eslint": "10.1.0",
  "eslint": "^6.8.0"

Use command: **npm install eslint@6.x babel-eslint@10 --save-dev**

Answer (score 3):

/Users/gi go to this and type npm i babel-eslint@10.1.0 It would solve your problem. Its worked for me

Answer (score 1):

My problem was solved by deleting **node_modules** that was in my "*C:\Users*" folder.

Answer (score 1):

A quick fix is creating a file named .env in the project folder with the following content
`SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true`

I couldn't get anything else to work, npm, yarn, deleting lock, deleting node_modules, etc. This is just happening in my linux mint environment, not on windows or ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

I followed some steps its work for me.

step 1: change your project location as if you saved it on `D drive` change its to `E drive`.

step 2: Delete node modules.

step 3: Install node modules with run this command >> npm install

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was searching on my Mac for all instances of node_modules, deleting all of them, going to the directory that you want to host these files, then re-running the following commands in the terminal in that directory:

```
--> npm install -g create-react-app
--> create-react-app jsx
```

(change to your React directory (i.e. name of your React project, in my case it is 'jsx'))

```
--> npm start
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this kind of error when I create a react project inside another react project. If you have the react project inside another react project this kind of error will be common.