# Get " a different version of webpack was detected higher up in the tree" error in CRA react app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, webpack

I am getting this error while running `npm start` on my CRA app. I tried uninstalling and installing webpack. Only thing that works is,
creating a ".env" file at the root with `SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true`.

`

> hello@0.1.0 start C:\Users\USER\Desktop\MyReact\REACT_HOOKS\hello
> react-scripts start
> There might be a problem with the project dependency tree.
> It is likely not a bug in Create React App, but something you need to fix locally.
> The react-scripts package provided by Create React App
> requires a dependency:
> "webpack": "4.42.0"
> Don't try to install it manually: your package manager
> does it automatically.
> However, a different version of webpack was detected higher up in the tree:
> C:\Users\USER\node_modules\webpack (version: 4.43.0)
> Manually installing incompatible versions is known to cause hard-to-debug issues.
> If you would prefer to ignore this check, add SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true to an .env file in your project.
> That will permanently disable this message but you might encounter other issues.
> To fix the dependency tree, try following the steps below in the exact order:

1. Delete package-lock.json (not package.json!) and/or yarn.lock in your project folder.
2. Delete node_modules in your project folder.
3. Remove "webpack" from dependencies and/or devDependencies in the package.json file in your project folder.
4. Run npm install or yarn, depending on the package
   manager you use.
   In most cases, this should be enough to fix the problem.
   If this has not helped, there are a few other things you can try:
5. If you used npm, install yarn (http://yarnpkg.com/) and repeat the above steps with it instead.
   This may help because npm has known issues with package hoisting which may get resolved in future versions.
6. Check if C:\Users\USER\node_modules\webpack is outside your project directory.
   For example, you might have accidentally installed something in your home folder.
7. Try running npm ls webpack in your project folder. This will tell you which other package (apart from the expected react-scripts) installed webpack.
   If nothing else helps, add SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true to an .env file in your project.
   That would permanently disable this preflight check in
   case you want to proceed anyway.
   P.S. We know this message is long but please read the steps above  We hope you find them helpful!
   npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
   npm ERR! errno 1
   npm ERR! hello@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
   npm ERR! Exit status 1
   npm ERR!
   npm ERR! Failed at the hello@0.1.0 start script.
   npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
   `

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NPM start returns error, "There might be a problem with the project dependency tree"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56528222/npm-start-returns-error-there-might-be-a-problem-with-the-project-dependency-t)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I ran `npm uninstall -g webpack` it didn't do anything.

then I ran both

```
npm uninstall -g webpack
npm uninstall webpack
```

and it's not showing the error anymore.

so apparently

```
npm uninstall webpack
```

worked.

Probably the issue was caused by a manual download of webpack.

Answer (score 3):

I ran `npm uninstall webpack`, `delete package.lock.json`, and then `run yarn`.
If you prefer npm, then instead of running yarn , you run `npm install`.

This will re-install webpack the right way in the dependency tree.