# Jest: testEnvironmentOptions cannot be read

Tags: unit-testing, jestjs

I'm getting the following error with Jest, but unclear why even after adding the testEnvironmentOptions

```
       TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'testEnvironmentOptions')
    
          at new JSDOMEnvironment (node_modules/jest-environment-jsdom/build/index.js:72:28)
          at async TestScheduler.scheduleTests (node_modules/@jest/core/build/TestScheduler.js:333:13)
          at async runJest (node_modules/@jest/core/build/runJest.js:404:19)
```

Here is my Jest config in my `package.json`:

```json
    "jest": {
        "moduleNameMapper": {
          "^@/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/$1",
          "^~/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/$1",
          "^vue$": "vue/dist/vue.common.js"
        },
        "testEnvironment": "jsdom",
        "testEnvironmentOptions": {
          "browsers": [
            "chrome",
            "firefox",
            "safari"
          ]
        },
        "moduleFileExtensions": [
          "vue",
          "js",
          "json"
        ],
        "transformIgnorePatterns": [
          "/node_modules/(?!crypto-random-string)"
        ],
        "transform": {
          "^.+\\.js$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/babel-jest",
          ".*\\.(vue)$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/vue-jest"
        },
        "collectCoverage": true,
        "collectCoverageFrom": [
          "<rootDir>/src/**/*.vue",
          "<rootDir>/src/**/*.js"
        ]
      }
```

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Make sure you have both packages `jest` and `jest-environment-jsdom` installed in the same version. The latter is required to be installed separately from `jest` version 28 on. I ran into the same issue when downgrading `jest` to 27.x but not `jest-environment-jsdom`. Have a look at the [version 27 to 28 upgrade guide about using JSDOM test environment](https://jest-archive-august-2023.netlify.app/docs/28.x/upgrading-to-jest28#jsdom).

Comment: Boy I spent a couple of days already toiling away at this! THANK YOU for the tip of installing them separately! I owe you a beer, sir!

Comment: Is this how it is supposed to be? "devDependencies": {
    "jest": "^28.1.2",
    "jest-environment-jsdom": "^28.1.2"
  }

Comment: @AmirŠaran Yes, for example. Is it working?

Comment: If you have jest installed globally as I do, make sure to update it too. Otherwise, running `jest` from your terminal will result in the same error.

Comment: https://jestjs.io/docs/upgrading-to-jest29#jsdom-upgrade

Comment: Adding this helpful article for people still find it difficult to do it. 
https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/jest-typeerror-cannot-read-properties-of-undefined-reading-testenvironmentoptions

Answer (score 7):

I had different versions of **local** **jest** and **global** **jest**, jest-environment-jsdom was not installed globally. This caused me the issues. Running it locally via

```
./node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js src/my-test.spec.ts
```

or updating global jest packages did the job for me.
I see that this is mentioned in one of the comments above, but somehow I missed it and spent too much time on it so posting it here

Comment: Using pnpm workspaces, in my project I needed to add a local dependency on `jest-cli` that matched the local `jest` version.

Comment: Thank you @Sly_cardinal, that was precisely my issue also. Arggggh

Comment: Indeed, I had the same situation, but using `npx jest src/my-test.spec.ts` is simpler to use the project's jest :)

Answer (score 4):

For me running

```
npx browserslist@latest --update-db
```

did the job

Comment: surprisingly for me too.

Comment: Same for me even though I had a message suggesting I do it which I ignored

Answer (score 2):

I used `yarn jest` instead of `jest` to run the tests and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

For those who still need a solution, try to check if you have a global version of the problematic library (in this case "jest-environment-node").

if you have it installed globally and the versions are different (from the running project version) you'll get errors.

I had the same issue with "jest" and with "babel-jest" when I tried to run yarn start (got a long error that started with "There might be a problem with the project dependency tree")

deleting these folders from the global path solved the problem.

the global path in Mac is usually /Users/{user}/node_modules/

good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I removed `testEnvironment: 'node'` and it works perfectly