# Can't host a development server for react in vs code

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I am new to react and i was hosting a development server . But whenever i npm start it i get the following error in the image. I was having issue while hosting create-react-app too but that worked when I installed the node js 14 version.

[image]

Comment: Did you try the fix suggested in the error message?

Comment: @rayhatfield yes I followed the steps but couldn't work it out

Comment: This question is already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56528222/npm-start-returns-error-there-might-be-a-problem-with-the-project-dependency-t). So I would suggest you implement the solutions as mentioned in the above question. After that hopefully, your issue will be fixed.

Comment: Please do not use screenshots of your code or error messages and do not link to external sources. Screenshots are hard to read on mobile devices, they cannot be searched and none of us can copy, paste and run an image, links can get 

obsolete. Code should be included as text in the question itself. For more on this see 
[**Why may I not upload images of code**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) 
on SO when asking a question?